# issue with number format as text in excel vba

Tags: excel, text, numbers, format, vba

I'm trying to convert cell number format as text with conditions. Unfortunately the VBA flashes an error:

> "Run-time error '438:' Object doesn't support this property or method.

My code is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lcell As Long

    lcell = Range("B90000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 8 To lcell
        If Range("L" & i) <> "" And Range("B8") <> "" Then
            Range("M" & i).NumberFormat = "@"
            Range("N" & i).NumberFormat = "@"
        End If
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Please help me in finding the mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you missing something here, I'm not able to reproduce the error.  What does the data look like?

Comment: Why would you want to do this everytime you select a different cell on the worksheet?

Comment: Shouldn't B8 in `... And Range("B8") <> "" ...` be `"B" & i` ?

Comment: Note: Instead of using a fixed range `Range("B90000").End(xlUp).Row` always use `Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
` to find the last used row. Also please tell in which line you get the error.